# Android Sqlite handler in separate thread?

Tags: android, multithreading, sqlite, thread-safety

My app requires high data throughput.  It receives an incoming data stream over bluetooth and has to parse it, scale it, display it, and store the data.

After reading up on different storage methods, I've decided to try to use Sqlite for data storage.  I've read up and it seems to get the best write performance, I should use transactions.

But before I even go there, I'm wondering if the DB handler should just be in it's own thread. The BT data processing is already in a separate thread and works well. I see a lot of discussions about accessing sqlite from multiple threads, but I'm thinking I want one thread handling the DB connection and just use intents to get/store data..mostly just to disconnect the display from the data storage.

Will this increase my performance, or is it not worth it?

I'm guessing I'll be writing 20-50 rows a second with up to 19 fields.

Answer (score 0):

Remember that SQLite is totally memory-resident. There is no disk latency time to slow up processing. As such, I would first try to keep the architecture as simple as possible to avoid creating any unnecessary overhead.